# Trying to chain multiple actions together in my component

Tags: reactjs, redux-thunk

In my react component I am trying to chain together multiple actions like so:

```
componentDidMount() {
  dispatch(Actions.fetchUser(userId)).then(() => {
    dispatch(Actions.fetchAbc(abcId)).then(() => {
      dispatch(Actions.fetchDef(defId));
    });
  });     
}
```

Each action is following the same pattern as fetchUser, where it returns a dispatch:

```
fetchUser: (userId) => {
  return dispatch => {
    let url = "....";
    axios.get(url)
      .then(function(resp) {        
        dispatch({
          type: Constants.SomeAction,
          user: resp.data.user,
        });
      });
  };
},
```

In my component I am seeing an error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'then' of undefined

The error is on the same line as the first .then call (fetchUser).

Is this not the correct way to chain together my actions?

Timing wise I have to do one after the other.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dispatching a thunk returns the return value of the thunk function, but yours isn't returning anything. Try:

```
fetchUser: (userId) => {
  return dispatch => {
    let url = "....";
    // return the promise so you can chain on it
    return axios.get(url)
      .then(function(resp) {        
        dispatch({
          type: Constants.SomeAction,
          user: resp.data.user,
        });
      });
  };
},
```

You need to make sure you're returning the promise returned by `axios`, as that is what you want to chain off with the subsequent `then`.

---

Looking more broadly at cases where you have to ensure actions are dispatched in a particular order, it will differ a bit based on whether your actions are synchronous or asynchronous (where you async actions will generally return a promise).

Synchronous events are easy, you can simply call them sequentially:

```
dispatch(syncAction1())
dispatch(syncAction2())
dispatch(syncAction3())
```

For async actions, you'll want to ensure that each action returns a promise, and then chain them off each (rewriting your `componentDidMount` function to point out some other issues):

```
dispatch(Actions.fetchUser(userId))
  // You need to ensure that your handler functions returns the result of the
  // next async dispatch
  .then(() => {
    return dispatch(Actions.fetchAbc(abcId))
  })
  // More simply, if you're only doing on thing then you can use the shorter
  // form of arrow function, which implicitly returns the result      
  .then(() => dispatch(Actions.fetchDef(defId))
```

If you have situations where you need a combination of the two, you can do that too:

```
dispatch(syncAction1())
dispatch(asyncAction2())
  .then(() => {
    dispatch(syncAction3())
    return dispatch(asyncAction4())
  })
  .then(() => dispatch(asyncAction5))
```

(Where the async actions are thunks that return a promise, but the sync actions could be either plain objects or synchronous thunks.)

Comment: For actions that don't really have any return value, how can I mimick one that just returns true?  I tried ```return true``` but i'm guessing it has to be asyc somehow?

Comment: It depends on what you're trying to do. If you want to chain off the action (as in your question) you need to return the promise that you want to chain off (i.e. the promise chain starting with your axios call, which will ultimately resolve with the action your dispatching on success). You're not returning it because you're interesting in the return value as much as knowing when the promise has resolved.

Comment: I have some actions that just dispatch, no axios call is made.  So how can I just return a ```return true``` in that case but asynch?

Comment: There's no need to do anything special with async actions, you just do the next action afterwards as a separate dispatch (not chained off the previous one). Have added some more examples about ensuring dispatch order with a mix of sync and async actions, but if you still have questions might help to have a more concrete example.